# executing a block of code at a certain exact time in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I want to execute a block of code (which includes recursive setTimeout) at a certain exact time in javascript.By writing get_current function i get the current time and with setInterval method with 1 mili second interval i compare the current time( fetched from get_current function) with my desired time and if that condition satisfies i execute a block of code recursively. i test my code with console messages and i understand that only once this code is executed and if statement is checked only once.
could any one help me doing that???

```
var dateString;
var delay=1500;

function get_current() {
    var mydate = new Date();
    var mili_real = mydate.getMilliseconds();
    var hour_real=mydate.getHours();
    var minute_real=mydate.getMinutes();
    var second_real=mydate.getSeconds();
    if(minute_real<10)minute_real="0"+minute_real;
    if(hour_real==0)hour_real="12";
    if(second_real<10) second_real="0"+second_real;
    if(mili_real<10)mili_real="00"+mili_real;
    else if(mili_real<100) mili_real="0"+mili_real;

    dateString=hour_real+""+minute_real+""+second_real+""+mili_real;        
}

setInterval(checkStart(),1);

function checkStart() {
    get_current();
    if (dateString == 145412578) {
        var timerId = setTimeout(
            function request() {                               
                console.log("request"+delay);
                if(delay<1600){
                    delay++;
                } else {
                    delay--;
                }
                timerId=setTimeout(request,dealy);

        }, delay);      
    } else {
        console.log("waiting to start");
    }
}
```

Comment: `setInterval(checkStart(),1);` should be `setInterval(checkStart,1);`. Right now, you're executing the function once, and "_executing_" its return value (`undefined`) at an interval. Also, in the `checkStart` function, you have `dealy`, which should probably be `delay`. Also, putting an interval of 1ms and expecting the value to `==` your wanted time is very unlikely. `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are not that precise. You'll need to allow for some threshold

Answer (score 0):

First, let's take a look at the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp): It says that `setInterval` takes two main parameters. There are optionally additional parameters to pass to the `function` when it's called, but let's ignore those and focus on the first two parameters. The second parameter is the time in milliseconds, which is clear for you. The first parameter is a `function`. Let's see your call

```
setInterval(checkStart(),1);
```

You pass `checkStart()` as your first parameter. It's a `function` call. There is no `return` in that `function`, which means that it "returns" `undefined`. So, your code above is functionally equivalent with the following:

```
checkStart();
setInterval(undefined,1);
```

So, the solution should be to pass the function instead its result to `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(checkStart,1);
```

and as a result, `checkStart` should be regularly called.

Comment: yes. you are right. thanks for your helpful recommendation but unfortunately it does not solve my problem. since i use a function recursively i can not apply your recommendation. do have any idea about it? how can i call the checkStart in my setInterval?

Comment: you can nest functions: timerId=setTimeout(function(){},dealy); and you do not need to call checkstart the whole purpose of the timer is to make the calls for you

Comment: @alibesharat you do not need to call checkStart in your setInterval. setInterval will call it for you.